# Remove selection when selected item gets deleted from ListBox

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBox` that has its `ItemsSource` bound to a custom class that (properly) implements an `INotifyCollectionChanged` and a `SelectedItem` bound to a field in a ViewModel.

The problem is that when I remove a currently `SelectedItem` from the `ItemsSource` collection it immediately changes the selection to an neighboring item. I would very much prefer if it just removed selection.

The reason why it's such a problem for me is following. The `ItemsSource` class contains elements from some other collection that either satisfy some (during runtime constant) Predicate or are `Active`. Being `Active` is "synchronized" with being `SelectedItem` (there're reasons for that). So it's very much possible for an item be allowed in the `ListBox` only if it's selected which means it might be supposed to vanish when user selects some other one.

My function (deep in "model") that gets called when `SelectedItem` gets changed:

```
//Gets old Active item
var oldActiveSchema = Schemas.FirstOrDefault(sch => sch.IsActive);

//Makes the new Item active (which triggers adding it into `ItemsSource` in case it didn't satisfy the Predicate)
((PowerSchema)newActiveSchema).IsActive = true;
//Triggers PropertyChanged on ViewModel with the new Active item
CurrentSchema = newActiveSchema;
RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(CurrentSchema)); (#1)

//Changes the old item so it stops being Active -> gets removed from `ItemsSource` (#2)
if (oldActiveSchema != null) { ((PowerSchema)oldActiveSchema).IsActive = false; }
```

The issue is that for some reason an update of `ListBox` due to the change of `SelectedItem` that's supposed to get triggered by (#1) gets postponed (the message to update the `ListBox` probably ends up in a WPF message loop and waits there until current computation finishes).

The removal of `oldActiveSchema` from the `ItemsSource`, on the other hand, is immediate and also instantly triggers a change of `SelectedItem` to a one that's next to the old one (when you remove the selected item, a neighboring gets selected instead). And because the change of `SelectedItem` triggers my function that sets `CurrentSchema` to the wrong (neighboring) item it rewrites the user-selected `CurrentSchema` (#1) and by the time the message to update `ListBox` due to `PropertyChanged` gets run it just updates it with the neighboring one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Actual code if anyone would like to dig deeper:

- [ListBox](https://github.com/petrroll/PowerSwitcher/blob/master/PowerSwitcher.TrayApp/MainWindow.xaml#L121)
- [ViewModel](https://github.com/petrroll/PowerSwitcher/blob/master/PowerSwitcher.TrayApp/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs#L16)
- [The model's method](https://github.com/petrroll/PowerSwitcher/blob/master/PowerSwitcher/PowerManager.cs#L91)
- [Callstack](http://pastebin.com/LbQnftuT) when neighboring item gets selected as `SelectedItem` instead of the one user chose

  - line 46: the `SelectedItem` chosen by user enters the method as one that's supposed to get active
  - line 45: the old `SelectedItem` stops being active -> gets removed from collection (44-41)
  - line 32: `MoveCurrencyOffDeletedElement` moves `SelectedItem`
  - line 5: `SelectedItem` gets changed to a neighboring one

Comment: Removing selection should just require setting the SelectedItem property in your ViewModel to null.  Since the problem is a schema change, just store your selecteditem in a local variable, set selecteditem to null, and *then* delete the selected item from the collection.

Comment: Drop in [#WPF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) and leave me a ping if i'm not active in chat. I had a look at your code but can't immediately figure out how to trigger the issue. There's also quite a few other helpful residents there who can lend a hand if I'm inactive.

Comment: And indeed Brandon's idea of selection change is what I was thinking too. Also if you bind Selector.IsSelected to IsActive .. your selection can automatically follow the IsActive flag without having to deal with current item

Comment: After looking at your code, you specifically ignore the set attempt if the value is null, but the only way to remove a selection is to set the selected value to null.  This being the case, what do you want to happen?  Will CurrentSchema being null cause errors?

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't make much sense for the model to have no Item selected, I can work around that, though. That said, my intuition was that deleting the currently selected element would force the View to remove selection, force null as Selected item (which wouldn't propagate to model due to the ignore), and then, when the message invoked by `#1` gets processed the View would load the correct currently selected item (set by line above `#1`) and everything would work well.

Comment: I don't really see how storing the selecteditem, setting it to null, and then deleting it would help. Because in that case the update of View's selection forced by setting it to null would still get processed only after the removal is already done. The same way as it happens now with the update forced by line #1 and the one above. Or am I missing something?

I'll look into binding trough IsActive, that might completely mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Diagnosis

The key to your problems is that you set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on your `ListBox`. What it does is it keeps the `ListBox.SelectedItem` and `ListBox.Items.CurrentItem` in sync. Also, `ListBox.Items.CurrentItem` is synchronized with the `ICollectionView.CurrentItem` property of the default collection view for the source collection (this view is returned by `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Schemas)` in your case). Now when you remove an item from the `Schemas` collection which also happens to be the `CurrentItem` of the corresponding collection view, the view by default updates its `CurrentItem` to the next item (or the previous one if the removed item was the last one, or to `null` if the removed item was the only item in the collection).

The second part of the problem is that when the `ListBox.SelectedItem` is changed causing an update to your view-model property, your `RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(ActiveSchema))` is processed **after** the update process is finished, in particular after the control is returned from the `ActiveSchema` setter. You can observe that the getter is not hit immediately, but only after the setter is done. What's important, the `CurrentItem` of the `Schemas` view is also not updated immediately to reflect the newly selected item. On the other hand, when you set `IsActive = false` on the previously selected item, it causes immediate "removal" of this item from the `Schemas` collection, which in turn causes an update of the `CurrentItem` of the collection view, and the chain immediately continues to update the `ListBox.SelectedItem`. You can observe that at this point the `ActiveSchema` setter will be hit again. So your `ActiveSchema` will be changed again (to the item next to the previously selected one) even before you've finished processing the previous change (to the item selected by the user).

## Solution

There are several ways to address this issue:

**#1**

Set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` on your `ListBox` (or leave it untouched). This will make your problem go away with no effort. If however for some reason it is required, use any of the other solutions.

**#2**

Prevent reentrant attempts to set the `ActiveSchema` by using a guard flag:

```
bool ignoreActiveSchemaChanges = false;
public IPowerSchema ActiveSchema
{
    get { return pwrManager.CurrentSchema; }
    set
    {
        if (ignoreActiveSchemaChanges) return;
        if (value != null && !value.IsActive)
        {
            ignoreActiveSchemaChanges = true;
            pwrManager.SetPowerSchema(value);
            ignoreActiveSchemaChanges = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This will cause automatic updates to the collection view's `CurrentItem` to be ignored by your view-model, and ultimately the `ActiveSchema` will maintain the expected value.

**#3**

Manually update the collection view's `CurrentItem` to the newly selected item before you "remove" the previously selected one. You will need a reference to the `MainWindowViewModel.Schemas` collection, so you can either pass it as a parameter to your `setNewCurrSchema` method or encapsulate the code in a delegate and pass that as the parameter. I'll only show the second option:

In the `PowerManager` class:

```
//we pass the action as an optional parameter so that we don't need to update
//other code that uses this method
private void setNewCurrSchema(IPowerSchema newActiveSchema, Action action = null)
{
    var oldActiveSchema = Schemas.FirstOrDefault(sch => sch.IsActive);

    ((PowerSchema)newActiveSchema).IsActive = true;
    CurrentSchema = newActiveSchema;
    RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(CurrentSchema));

    action?.Invoke();

    if (oldActiveSchema != null)
    {
        ((PowerSchema)oldActiveSchema).IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

In the `MainWindowViewModel` class:

```
public IPowerSchema ActiveSchema
{
    get { return pwrManager.CurrentSchema; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null && !value.IsActive)
        {
            var action = new Action(() =>
            {
                //this will cause a reentrant attempt to set the ActiveSchema,
                //but it will be ignored because at this point value.IsActive == true
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Schemas).MoveCurrentTo(value);
            });
            pwrManager.SetPowerSchema(value, action);
        }
    }
}
```

Note though that this requires a reference to the `PresentationFramework` assembly. If you don't want that dependency in your view-model assembly, you could create an event which would be subscribed to by the view and the required code would be run by the view (which already depends on the `PresentationFramework` assembly). This method is often referred to as *interaction request pattern* (see [User Interaction Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx#UserInteractionPatterns)) section in the *Prism 5.0* guide on *MSDN*).

**#4**

Defer the "removal" of the previously selected item until the binding update is finished. This can be achieved by queueing the code to be executed using a [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void setNewCurrSchema(IPowerSchema newActiveSchema)
{
    var oldActiveSchema = Schemas.FirstOrDefault(sch => sch.IsActive);

    ((PowerSchema)newActiveSchema).IsActive = true;
    CurrentSchema = newActiveSchema;
    RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(CurrentSchema));

    if (oldActiveSchema != null)
    {
        //queue the code for execution
        //in case this code is called due to binding update the current dispatcher will be
        //the one associated with UI thread so everything should work as expected
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            ((PowerSchema)oldActiveSchema).IsActive = false;
        });
    }
}
```

This requires reference to the `WindowsBase` assembly, which again can be avoided in the view-model assembly by utilizing the method described for solution #3.

Personally I'd go with solution #1 or #2 because it keeps your `PowerManager` class clean, and #3 and #4 seem prone to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I had ideas similar to #3 and #4 but both of these solutions seemed to me to be a bit "dirty". Also I really didn't want to pollute `PowerManager` with UI related hacks.

#2 is a great idea. I didn't think about that one despite it being kind of obvious. I'll go with #1, though. I kind of misunderstood what `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=` does and thought it was required for my use case. Turned out it's not the case.